# Running script from remote server using ssh in python

Tags: python, ssh, remote-access, remote-server, paramiko

I want to run my python script from my local machine. But the python script named `script.py` is in remote server and it has some arguments and parameters.
I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='x.x.x.x', port=22, username='root', password='passwd')
stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command('python /root/file/script.py') #It has some argument I want to use them from my local machine
for i in stdout.readlines():
    print i.strip('\r\n')
ssh.close()
```

`script.py` has some arguments. how should I change this script in order to use arguments of `script.py` from my local machine?

Comment: Are you familiar with `sys.argv`? you can use it in your script to pass the argument in terminal! https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: Yes I am... But using arguments of script.py in this script is possible? how?

Comment: You can pass them in `ssh.exec_command` function! (but im not sure that this function support that!) but `os.system` support  that!

Answer (score 0):

It is more tricky than one would think, thanks to ssh not supporting argument lists:

```
import sys
try:
    from pipes import quote  # python 2
except ImportError:
    from shlex import quote  # python 3

ssh.exec_command('python /root/file/script.py ' +
    ' '.join([quote(i) for i in sys.argv[1:]])
)
```

When running `python myprogram.py argument\ with" quotes\" and spaces"`, this should pass `'argument with quotes" and spaces'` as 1 argument to the other program. Though I wouldn't vouch for paramiko always doing the right thing.

Comment: Thank you... But what is the last `)` you put it in answer part?

Comment: it happens to be the hanging closing parenthesis of the `ssh.exec_command` invocation